# Validate login script

Tags: php, validation, authentication

im trying to make a basic login script that requires the correct input to be used in order to login. I also want my script to bring up an error if the wrong details are input. 
I have looked around but i can't seem to find a fix for this as i don't want to use MySQL. 
I want to stick to html/PHP also.

I have the basic display of the login script:

```
<p><b>Please Login</b></p>
<form action="useraccess.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

If anyone could help me out here that would be greatly appreciated! 
cheers.

Comment: We are not here to write the code for you. That's YOUR job. We're just here to help you fix whatever it is you've written.

Comment: Never write stuff like that by yourself. Use something existing, made by people who know what they do, check out http://www.php-login.net

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Something like that:

```
<p><b>Please Login</b></p>
    <form action="useraccess.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>

<?php
session_start(); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $username = $_POST['username']; 
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password'){
      $_SESSION['loginsuccess'] = true; 
      header('location:accesssite.php'); 
      die();
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

useraccess.php

```
session_start();
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'pass';

$error = '';

if($_POST['username'] != $username) $error .= 'Wrong username!<br>';
if($_POST['pass'] != $password) $error .= 'Wrong username!<br>';

if(!empty($error) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;

    header('Location:form.php'); //your login script

}

...

continue as logged user
```

then in form.php (your login script)

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['error'])) echo $_SESSION['error']; ?>

....
....

Your login script
```